# Rectangle or Polygon with no filling

Tags: graphics

I have:

```
Graphics[{
  LightBlue, 
  Polygon[{{2/3, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {2/3, 0}}],
  EdgeForm[Black], White, Opacity[0],
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}],
  Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}],
  Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 2}],
  Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}],
  Red, Thick, Line[{{2/3, 0}, {3, 3}}]
  },
 Axes -> True]
```

But my red line does not show up. Could it have something to do with the way I constructed my rectangles. It is last, so I expected it to be on the top layer.

Maybe I should ask is there a way to use the Rectangle and Polygon command with no filling?

**Update (Thanks to Rahul):** Excellent advice. This worked.

```
Graphics[{
  LightBlue, 
  Polygon[{{2/3, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {2/3, 0}}],
  {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black],
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
   Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}],
   Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}],
   Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 2}],
   Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}]},
  Red, Thick, Line[{{2/3, 0}, {3, 3}}]
  },
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: It's because you set `Opacity[0]`, so the line is completely invisible. To disable filling, use `FaceForm[None]` instead.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the help. I learned a lot with the new FaceForm[None] command.

Answer (score 4):

```
Graphics[
 {
  LightBlue,
  (* valid until the next color spec *)
  Polygon[{{2/3, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {2/3, 0}}],

  EdgeForm[Black], White,
  Opacity[0],
  (* valid until the next opacity spec *)
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
  Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}],
  Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}],
  Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 2}],
  Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}],

  Red, Thick, 
  (* restore normal opacity *)
  Opacity[1],
  Line[{{2/3, 0}, {3, 3}}],
  },
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]